# pip install is working in notebook cell but not working in script

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, openai-gym

I am trying pip commands. I am installing OpenAI Gym. I wrote the following command in a notebook cell and run it: `pip install gym` It worked and gave me a message of successful installation.

But when I tryed typing the same command in a `.py` script file and run it, it gives me an error:

```
    pip install gym
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know that I already have the gym package installed on my machine since the successful execution in notebook. However, I think it should give me different message that it is already installed or updated like when I rerun the command again in notebook cell:

```
Requirement already satisfied: gym in c:\users\osama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.20.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.18.0 in c:\users\osama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.20.3)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle>=1.2.0 in c:\users\osama\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from gym) (1.6.0)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

I just need to understand !

Comment: The command using ! are not part of the python language, they are extensions in jupyter notebook, that is why they don't work in a script, only in notebooks.

Comment: I did not use the exclamation mark ```!``` here

Comment: You did in the notebook. Else it would not work.

Comment: I am sure that I did not add it in the notebook and it worked. I am using Jupyter notebook extension on VS code from Microsoft. Does it make any difference from the web-based version?

Comment: Yes it could make a difference. In any case these are not standard python commands and people already explained why they don't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+SyntaxError

Answer (score 1):

`pip` is a command line utility that works only on a terminal or command prompt window. Your .py script is a file for python code, and the pip command is not python code, therefore python does not recognize it and it gives you an error.

[Here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/getting-started/) is an official guide on how to get started using `pip`

Comment: So, why can it be run from notebook? Does this means that notebook can run terminal commands?

Comment: Yes @Osama,  a notebook can run terminal commands. Jupyter's Python-based kernel evolved from IPython notebook, which evolved out of the IPython project. All of those can run terminal commands if you use the right syntax. For `pip` you now want you use `%pip install` magic commands, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about that. But a lot of terminal commands have equivalents that automatically get used like `ls`, without you needing to put an exclamation point in front of it. And `%cd` is special.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install gym` is not python script.You should run it in system terminal like `Bash`, `PowerShell`,`Cmd` and so on to install required package.

Comment: So, why can it be run from notebook? Does this means that notebook can run terminal commands?

Comment: If you add `!` at the beginning of cell in jupyter, you will be able to run shell command after `!`.For example: `!pip install requests`

Comment: Don't use sheep's specific example. That was outdated when sheep wrote it. At that time and now, always use the magic command `%pip install` in modern, current Jupyter (and related `%conda install`). See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern magic install commands that insure installation occurs in the environment where the kernel is running that is underlying the active notebook.